# Permission Denied when reading S3 file with Spark in Python

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, pycharm

I am using PySpark to read S3 files in PyCharm. The following errors returned:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   o26.partitions. 
>       org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: s3n://2017/01/22/20/firenam:

code is like this :

```
hadoopConf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "myaccesskey")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "MySecretKey")
temp = sc.textFile("s3n://2017/01/22/filename")
temp.count()
```

When I am using Boto3 to download file from S3 with Python ,  it can succeed.

Change "s3n" to "s3a" still failed, with a different exception:

> error returned :  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
>     org/apache/hadoop/fs/GlobalStorageStatistics$StorageStatisticsProvider

I've also tried to export following environment variable:

> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = myaccesskey .
>   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = mysecretkey

or add them explicitly in os.environ, also failed.

My environment is:

> OS:  Mac Sierra 10.12.6
>   Spark: 2.2.0
>   Python: 3.6.1

I have the following submit parameter in code

```
SUBMIT_ARGS = "--master local[*] --jars /ExternalJar/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar,/ExternalJar/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar pyspark-shell"
```

The job is directly run in PyCharm IDE.

Anyone have clues ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you didn't set bucket name in `s3n://2017/01/22/filename`. The valid path should be `s3n://bucket_name/path_to_file`.